# How to hide div html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div id="more-hd more-vis"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div>  
 </div>
```

I am trying to hide the last Div.I use bootstrap.So,d-none doesn't help, in css `#more-hd display:none` also,with JS `document.getElementById("more-hd").style.display = "none"` too.It is always visible..I also tried with ul > li first..nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried Jquery Hide method.??

Comment: You can't have multiple IDs in an element. The ID is `more-hd more-vis`, not `more-hd`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `display: none !important;` to the last `div` add a class to the last div and use that css in that class. Using `!important` will override the  css that has already been applied to this div. You also have multiple `id`, it is a bad practice so use a single id there.

```css
.lastDiv{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div id="more-hd more-vis" class='lastDiv'>SomeContent<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div>  
</div>
```

If you want to use `id` then use a single `id` value with this code:

```css
#more-hd{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div id="more-hd" class='lastDiv'>SomeContent<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div>  
</div>
```

You also has option for `last-child` selector in css to make sure whatever the `id` or `class` is for the last `div` inside class `navigation-menu`, it is always hidden:

```css
.navigation-menu div:last-child{
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
          <div id="more-hd more-vis" class='lastDiv'>SomeContent<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you also use `:last-child`

> NOTE: ID is always unique. so there is no meaning of two id

```css
.navigation-menu div:last-child {
display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div id="more-hd"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>test</div>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Apply This Css.

```
.navigation-menu div:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space in the `id`. If you want to put CSS on `#more-hd`, it should be

```
id="more-hd"
```

not

```
id="more-hd more-vis"
```

If you need multiple ways to refer to the element, use classes for the additional ones. It can only have one ID.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navigation-menu .fa-chevron-circle-down{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="navigation-menu w-32 d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div class="visible"><a href="#">Раздел1</a></div>
   <div id="more-hd more-vis"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down">Test for hide</i></div>  
 </div>
```